# How can I place text that relates to a foreach function, outside the loop?

Tags: php, xml, foreach

I'm really unsure how to describe this, so please forgive me.

Basically, I'm reading from an XML, and then generating an IF statement that checks all records in the XML and if a condition matches, details about that record is displayed.

What I want to add, is a similar function but in reverse, but outside the foreach loop, so it's only displayed once.

```
foreach($xml as $Reader) { $items[] = $Reader; }
$items= array_filter($items, function($Reader) use ($exclude) {
    if($Reader->Picture == 'None' || in_array($Reader->Pin, $exclude)) { 
        return false;
    }   
        return true;
});
usort ($items, function($a, $b) { 
    return strcmp($a->Status,$b->Status); 
});
foreach($items as $Reader) {
    if($Reader->Status == 'Available' && !in_array($Reader->Pin, $exclude)) {
        echo "<a href='/details?Pin=".$Reader->Pin."'>".$Reader->Name ." (".$Reader->Pin.")</a> is available! ...&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    }
}
if (!$items) { echo "Please check back in a moment when our readers will be available!"; }
```

So, in the XML file each Reader has a Status that can be one of three values: Available, Busy or Logged Off.

So what I'm doing, is for each record in the XML, checking if the Reader status is available.. and if so, echo the above line.

But I want to add in, that if NONE of the readers show as 'Available' to echo a single line that says 'Please check back in a moment'.

With the code above, ifthere are four readers online, but they're all busy.. nothing is displayed.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you want to do, but in a foreach you can use references, so foreach($items as &$reader), maybe thats waht you are looking for?

Comment: The point of what I'm trying to get at, is to not include it within the foreach loop, which is what an else will do. There's about 80 readers in the XML file, and I only want the message to appear once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a simple boolean value

```
$noneAvailable = true;
foreach($items as $Reader) {
    if($Reader->Status == 'Available' && !in_array($Reader->Pin, $exclude)) {
        echo "<a href='/details?Pin=".$Reader->Pin."'>".$Reader->Name ." (".$Reader->Pin.")</a> is available! ...&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        $noneAvailable = false;
    }
}

if ($noneAvailable) {
  echo "Please check back in a moment";
}
```

Comment: This gets confused when some readers are Available, and some are Busy.. it will print the available ones, and then display the message afterwards

Comment: I am be no means an PHP expert, but if the available ones are printed, it means `$noneAvailable` is set to false. This means, the `if` below is false and the echo will not be executed.

Comment: I used this as a basis and generated my own. So will mark this as the answer

Comment: It definitely did both, anyway it's sorted now. I'll add the code I used actually, that'll be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I managed to take the answer given above, and combine it with XPath to just filter the records in the XML based on the status given using xPath.

```
include TEMPLATEPATH."/extras/get-readers.php";
$readers = $xml->xpath('/ReaderDetails/Reader[Status="Available"]');
$gotOps = false;
foreach ($readers as $Reader)
    {
        echo "<a href='/details?Pin=".$Reader->Pin."'>".$Reader->Name ." (".$Reader->Pin.")</a> is available! ...&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        $gotOps = true;
    }
if ($gotOps!=true)
    {
        echo 'Please check back in a moment when our readers will be available!';
    }
```

Comment: In this case, you can skip the `$gotOps` and simply check for `!count($readers)`, i.e. checking that the array is non-empty. Also, instead of `$gotOps!=true` always use `!$gotOps`, it is shorter and much more standard.